# Symfony get Values from Entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

Is there a possibility to read all available Values from an entity?

E.G.

```
class Properties
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="UserID", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $userID;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Sport", type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $sport;

.
.
.
```

So that I will get the name of the Value like: Id, UserID, Sport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read the info you need thru the Doctrine metadata info as follow:

```
    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get("doctrine");
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();

    $className = "Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Properties";

    $metadata = $em->getClassMetadata($className);

    $nameMetadata = $metadata->fieldMappings['sport'];

    echo $nameMetadata['type'];  //print "string"
    echo $nameMetadata['length']; // print "1"

    // OR query for all fields
    // Returns an array with all the identifier column names. 
    $metadata->getIdentifierColumnNames();
```

More info on the [API DOC](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.2/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataInfo.html)

Hope this help

Comment: Greast. I use now "getColumnNames" so I will recive all Names. Thank you. thats awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `ReflectionClass::getProperties()` to loop through all properties.

http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php